# Whenever I kill a Select query on SQL Server Always On Cluster, it goes to ROLLBACK and hangs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, alwayson

Whenever I kill a Select query on SQL Server Always On Cluster, it goes to ROLLBACK and hangs.

Do I need to stop the synchronous commit mode with the secondary and then kill the session and then start the sync ?

Answer (score 0):

> it goes to ROLLBACK and hangs.

this may appear to be hang,but it is rolling back internally

> Do I need to stop the synchronous commit mode with the secondary and then kill the session and then start the sync ?

this wont make any difference ,since the log blocks should be replicated and will replicate once you resume always on

Let the query rollback

Comment: Thanks for the response. But why would a SELECT statement ROLLBACK ?
This is causing a lot of issue in my production system.

Comment: Can you share your entire query and output of sp_who2 when you say it is rolling back

Comment: Following is the query that is giving me trouble.
Its a simple SELECT statement but goes for a Rollback when I kill it. Can you please suggest ?

SELECT 
                IsNull(Sum(HpFtrslsbydt.[POS Qty]), 0) AS [POS Qty], 
                I
FROM 
                Table AS Ftrslsbydt WITH (NOLOCK) 
                INNER JOIN OrcaHpFuzzyTimeDate AS HpFzzytmdt WITH (NOLOCK) 
                                ON HpFtrslsbydt.[Date] = HpFzzytmdt.[Date]